# How to ensure shapes in Photoshop only use complete pixels

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize, shapes

When using Photoshop for designing pixel-based layouts (websites, apps etc.), is there a way to ensure that when you're using the shapes tool, or resizing a layer, it always snaps to a complete pixel? I know when you use the marquee tool it snaps to pixels, but then as soon as you resize that layer it could become 20.40 px wide, and I want to lock it to 20 or 21. Is that possible? Any help appreciated!

Comment: Near duplicate: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/how-can-i-easily-create-a-shape-with-a-specific-pixel-width-and-height-in-photos

Answer (score 3):

You can enable snap to pixel when creating shapes. You can also enable the grid and set the grid lines to X pixels with X subdivisions. You can also align your objects to whole pixels and set their height/width to whole pixels. As well, you can use the marquee tool to select the bounding box of your object and create guides around it that your object can be snapped to.